# Is it possible to run an ImageJ script on heroku?

Tags: image-processing, heroku, imagej

I want to be able to upload images to a server through something like a RESTful API, which then processes the image using an [ImageJ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ImageJ) script and then returns numerical results (no image is returned)

Can this be done easily? and can it be built on Heroku?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ImageJ works well headless; see http://imagej.net/Headless. So you could certainly build a server application which uses ImageJ based on any of several different Java server platforms (JBoss, Glassfish, Jersey, etc.). Especially if you leverage the new [ImageJ2](http://imagej.net/ImageJ2) API, there is a good separation of concerns which would allow you to build an effective client-server application.

To my knowledge, however, no one has created such a thing yet. I started [playing with the idea](https://github.com/imagej/imagej-server) using Jersey, but there is nothing really there right now, nor any time to work on it. Contributions in this area would be most welcome!

See also the [ImageJ-OMERO project](https://github.com/imagej/imagej-omero), which exposes ImageJ commands (including scripts/macros) as [OMERO](https://openmicroscopy.org/) scripts which run on the server side.